# AttributeError: 'ExceptionResponse' object has no attribute 'registers' in pymodbus

Tags: python, pymodbus

I would like to read the temperature from an SMA STP6.0 solar inverter using code based on pymodbus using the modbus TCP protocol.

To start I run the Sunspec Client Example from https://pymodbus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/example/sunspec_client.html. This code fails with the following error message:

> AttributeError: 'ExceptionResponse' object has no attribute 'registers'

I'm running the sample code unchanged, using Python3 on Ubuntu.

```
DEBUG:__main__:reading device block[40000..40002]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/scripts/sma-modbus.py", line 301, in <module>
    client = create_sunspec_sync_client("192.168.178.110")
  File "/home/pi/scripts/sma-modbus.py", line 179, in create_sunspec_sync_client
    client.initialize()
  File "/home/pi/scripts/sma-modbus.py", line 225, in initialize
    decoder  = self.get_device_block(self.offset, 2)
  File "/home/pi/scripts/sma-modbus.py", line 266, in get_device_block
    return SunspecDecoder.fromRegisters(response.registers)
AttributeError: 'ExceptionResponse' object has no attribute 'registers'
```

I have researched this problem but didn't find a solution. Any help/pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: You are receiving an error response from your slave, you will have to explicitly check for positive response with `if not response.is_error(): return SunspecDecoder.fromRegisters(response.registers)`

Comment: Thank you. Do you mean I should change the code example from the module's author. If yes, which line do I have to change? I would have expected the example to work as-is.

Comment: @ Sanju: I tried the above code instead of the original line 266 but this also results in an error: AttributeError: 'ExceptionResponse' object has no attribute 'is_error'

Answer (score 0):

Your device does not seem to be supported by the script you're using. That's the reason you're getting an error, you're trying to read a Modbus address that has not been defined (it actually looks that you have no connectivity at all with your device, if you were reading the wrong address you'd be getting a different error, so first off make sure you have a connection with your device and that your port `502` is open and not filtered).

In any case, the Sunspec Client script only read info from the device and you should be able to recycle most of it.

You can try the following to read the internal temperature from your device:

```
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
# import the various server implementations
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusTcpClient as ModbusClient

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
# configure the client logging
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------- #
import logging
FORMAT = ('%(asctime)-15s %(threadName)-15s '
          '%(levelname)-8s %(module)-15s:%(lineno)-8s %(message)s')
logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT)
log = logging.getLogger()
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------#
# Define UNIT ID
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------#
UNIT = 126  # default according to the manual, see below

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------#
# Define client
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------#
client = ModbusClient('localhost', port=502)
client.connect()

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------- #
# Read temperature
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------- #
rr = client.read_holding_registers(219, 1, unit=UNIT) #see documentation linked below
print(rr.registers[0])

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------- #
# close the client
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------- #
client.close()
```

This script should work if you have the default device UNIT ID.

If you get an `error: Modbus address does not exist` it means for some reason your device has a different UNIT ID. You can read the address using the same script changing the following lines:

```
...
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------#
# Define UNIT ID
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------#
UNIT = 1  # default according to the manual, used for reading actual DEVICE ID

...
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------- #
# Read UNIT ID
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------- #
rr = client.read_holding_registers(2112, 1, unit=UNIT) #see documentation linked below
print(rr.registers[0])
....
```

I took the UNIT IDs and register numbers from the [prodcut documentation site](https://www.sma-sunny.com/en/technical-documentation-updates/). This is the [info package](http://files.sma.de/dl/24399/MODBUS-HTML_STP3-6-3AV-40_V11.zip) I used. There is also a [software section](https://www.sma.de/en/service/downloads.html) that you might want to check (I don't think you'll find any source code in there though).

If you want to read other than `int` values (for instance Power Drawn, which is `unsigned32` type) you should be able to recycle `class SunspecDecoder(BinaryPayloadDecoder):` from the Sunspec Client.

Note that according to the Modbus map of these devices you have to use `read_input_registers` for what the manufacturer calls the SMA Modbus Profile (on default UNIT ID 3) but `read_holding_registers` for the Sunspec Modbus Profile (on default UNIT ID 126).

And as a final disclaimer, I never used any of these inverters myself so my answer is only based on a quick review of the documentation. That means I cannot guarantee my answer will be 100% accurate, but I hope it would be useful nonetheless.

**EDIT**: I forgot to mention that when you're not sure about UNIT IDs or registers it is a good idea to grab a tool like [QModMaster](https://sourceforge.net/projects/qmodmaster/). This will allow you to quickly check settings in a couple of clicks. Once you're sure of what works you can go on to your code.

Comment: I have been using Modbus Master Simulator to verify the UNIT and REGISTER IDs. UNIT ID 3 yields the correct result in the above simulator. Running your code with UNIT ID 3 results in the following error: `AttributeError: 'ExceptionResponse' object has no attribute 'registers'` UNIT ID 126 completes OK but does not yield a useful result (65535). I'd be happy to show you the complete debug log, but I don't seem to be able to enter that many characters. A hint would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Well, it's something... I think you need to change the register number, try `2111` and `2113` instead

Comment: Interesting. With ID 3 both registers complete with 65535 and with ID 126 complete with 32768; both incorrect values. As an experiment I tried register 30977 for both IDs. They both results in the correct L1 AC current. Why would the simulator report the correct value for register 30953 and not while running the code? Why does 30977  return the correct value from the code? Very puzzling.

Comment: Sorry I jumped in too quickly. With the simulator you mean QModMaster? If so note if you're reading `holding registers` or `input registers`. You can change that on your script too: use `read_input_registers()` or `read_holding_registers()`

Comment: I was already using Modbus Master Simulator instead of QModMaster but that shouldn't make a difference. I'm reading holding registers with both the simulator and your code so that's probably not the cause of this problem.

Comment: OK, clear. Something very strange indeed. I'm assuming you're connecting from the same computer and you don't have a firewall that might be filtering traffic.

Comment: Register 30977 is data type `Signed32` with these you need to read two registers and decode to get the correct value. When you say 30977 returned the correct value from the code, how do you know it's correct? You have values on a display I guess... what values did you use when reading with Python? i mean starting register, number of registers and UNIT ID. (`read_holding_registers(starting register, number of registers, UNIT ID)`

Comment: Answer to your first question: the simulator and the code run on different machines but I'm 100% certain that the connectivity is fine as shown by the logfile of your code.

Comment: Response to your second comment: I'm using 4 test cases: 2 for SMA and SunSpec IDs and 2 for 2 different registers. Here's the relevant code:
    if spec == 'SunSpec':
        UNIT = 126
        # register = 40219  # internal temperature
        register = 40189  # L1 AC current
        n_registers = 1
    elif spec == 'SMA':
        UNIT = 3
        # register = 30953  # internal temperature
        register = 30977  # L1 AC current
        n_registers = 2
continued in next comment...

Comment: ...continued
SMA and 30977 yield 3672. This is the correct current in mA as shown by the web interface
SunSpec and 40189 yield 36.
SMA and 30953 yield 448. This is the correct temperature x 10
SunSpec and 40219 yield 32768 -> ERROR
Conclusion: something must have changed as SMA now gives the correct results while SunSpec never gives a meaningful result. 

It seems the problem is solved but I still don't know what went wrong.

Comment: Looks a bit better then. I think it might make sense: focusing on the current (SMA reg. 30977) if you look at the Modbus map it indicates a scaling factor of 40192... So, what does that mean? No idea, but digging in the introduction to Modbus document (the pdf) they say `SunSpec scale factor as signed integer (16 bit). Scale factors are used as exponents of a power of ten. Negative scale factors push the decimal point to the left, positive scale factors to the right.` Nice, huh? I'm assuming you have to read register 40192 to find this exponent? Really contorted documentation...

Comment: ...but not the worst I've seen. So I think if you read register 40192 you'll find a 2 in there meaning you have to multiply what you got on register 40189 (36) times 10^2, what is 36*100=3600, which is not far away from what you got from the SMA (3672). I think that might be it.